# Generate a lot of struct types that have the same functionality as float (System.Single)

Tags: c#, code-generation

I've created a code base where I heavily rely on the `float` struct. But a float can mean anything. Seconds, Meters, Radians, Kilos, Meters per second, Radian per second, etc.... Proper naming helps, but its still easy to mix things up. So I started write structs that wrap a float, for each unit. But its becoming increasingly cumbersome to write structs that:

- store their underlying float value
- all their operator (<, <=, >, >=, ==, !=, -, +, *, /)
- a proper Equals, GetHashCode, and ToString method
- The implementation of the IEquatable interface

What is the easiest way to generate such structs so that I do not have to maintain so much code?

Bonus questions: In such a way that I'm, still able to add some special operators. For example, I would like to add an operator that turns `Meters` / `Seconds` in `MetersPerSecond`.

*Edit: I'm on .Net Framework 4.7 and C# language level 7.3*

Here's my example `Seconds` struct. As you can imagine the Meters struct looks exactly the same.

```
public struct Seconds : IEquatable<Seconds>
{
    public Seconds(float value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public float Value { get; }

    public static implicit operator Seconds(float value) => new Seconds(value);

    public static implicit operator Seconds(TimeSpan value) => new Seconds((float)value.TotalSeconds);

    public static Seconds operator +(Seconds a, Seconds b) => new Seconds(a.Value + b.Value);

    public static Seconds operator -(Seconds a, Seconds b) => new Seconds(a.Value - b.Value);

    public static bool operator >(Seconds a, Seconds b) => a.Value > b.Value;

    public static bool operator <(Seconds a, Seconds b) => a.Value < b.Value;

    public static bool operator >=(Seconds a, Seconds b) => a.Value >= b.Value;

    public static bool operator <=(Seconds a, Seconds b) => a.Value <= b.Value;

    public static bool operator ==(Seconds a, Seconds b) => a.Equals(b);

    public static bool operator !=(Seconds a, Seconds b) => !a.Equals(b);

    public override int GetHashCode() => this.Value.GetHashCode();

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Seconds)
        {
            return this.Equals((Seconds)obj);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Seconds other) => other.Value == this.Value;

    public override string ToString() => $"{this.Value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}s";
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do that. Just name your variables accordingly, or use a class (make your own or use `Timespan`, for example) that has properties like `Seconds`, `Minutes`, etc...

Comment: @RufusL I think proper naming doesn't prevent mistakes that could've easily been prevented by proper typing. And unfortunately I can't use classes as this code is used in a high performance parts of a render engine. Making it a class means that the instanced need to be collected by the GC and that the class becomes a lot heavier than the 32bits it should represent in memory. It also adds an extra step of indirection which messes with data locality.

Comment: You can do type aliases I.E. `using Seconds = System.Single`, etc. but that doesn't provide any actual type safety. Just either cleaner or more confusing syntax depending on how you look at it. Otherwise I've never found a way that doesn't involve a lot of boilerplate code w/ operators and conversions.

Comment: Have you considered using F# units of measure for business logic, then calling it from C#? https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/

Comment: @GregC, that's an interesting idea actually. I'll experiment with that!

Comment: If only C# had some kind of assembly-wide typedefs / type aliases, then a concept similar to C++'s std::chrono (they have two types, duration and time_point which have typedefs for milliseconds, seconds, minutes, hours, etc.) might be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay with C#, you could use a simple [Yellicode](https://www.yellicode.com) template to generate the boilerplate code (using a bit of TypeScript). Here's a template that generates partial structs (`struct-types.template.ts`).

```
import { Generator, TextWriter } from '@yellicode/templating';
import { CSharpWriter } from '@yellicode/csharp';

var structNames = ['Seconds', 'Meters']; // add more names here 

Generator.generate({ outputFile: './structs.cs' }, (output: TextWriter) => {
    var csharp = new CSharpWriter(output);
    structNames.forEach(structName => {     
        const struct: StructDefinition = { name: structName, accessModifier: 'public', isPartial: true, implements: [`IEquatable<${structName}>`] } as StructDefinition;
        csharp.writeStructBlock(struct, () => {
            // Ctor            
            csharp.writeMethodBlock({ isConstructor: true, name: structName, accessModifier: 'public', parameters: [{ typeName: 'float', name: 'value' }] }, () => {
                csharp.writeLine('this.Value = value;');
            });
            csharp.writeLine();
            // Value            
            csharp.writeAutoProperty({ typeName: 'float', name: 'value', accessModifier: 'public', hasGetter: true });
            csharp.writeLine();
            // Operators 
            csharp.writeLine(`public static implicit operator ${structName}(float value) => new ${structName}(value);`);
            csharp.writeLine();
            // ... other operators omitted for brevity, type-specific conversion operators would be in a partial file
            // Methods
            csharp.writeLine('public override int GetHashCode() => this.Value.GetHashCode();');
            csharp.writeLine();
            // ... other methods omitted for brevity
        })
        csharp.writeLine();
    })
});
```

The configuration file (`codegenconfig.json`) should look as follows:

```
{
    "compileTypeScript": true,
    "templates": [
        {
           "templateFile": "struct-types.template.ts"
        }
    ]
}
```

Quick start (make sure you have NPM installed, then open a command prompt):

1. `npm install @yellicode/cli -g`
2. Create a directory with the above files and run `npm init -y`
3. `npm install --save-dev @yellicode/templating  @yellicode/csharp`
4. Run `yellicode --watch` to generate your code.

If you want a separate output file for each struct, start with the `structNames.forEach(..` loop and call `Generator.generate(...` for each struct.

Comment: That's a great answer. Also the idea of using partial files is smart. I currently don't have a dependency on npm. But I'll definitely take a look at this.

Comment: @Roy T. Did you get a chance to take a look? I've updated the answer for version 1.3 of the [C# extension](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yellicode/csharp), which can take more structured input.

Comment: in the end I wrote a little bit of C# code to generate the simple structures I needed. A bit of a hack but the easiest solution, with the least dependencies :).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Units of Measure](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure) feature in F#.  It enforces units of measure at compile-time, doesn't affect performance.  Assembly made in F# can be easily used from C# if public surface is kept simple.  Units of measure slapped onto a float are compiled to System.Double in IL.

As far as the bonus is concerned, the units of measure are maintained and verified by compiler.  If meters are divided by seconds, the result will be in meters per second.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with F#, but as far as I can tell my code now generates a nice get hash code and equals. The other operators are still troublesome. But maybe it can be solved by someone who understands F# better. What I have now is:


`type Meters<[<Measure>]'u> =
        struct
            val value:float32<'u>
        end
        new (v) = {value = v}`

Comment: Ah I now found that its actually impossible to work well with Units of Measure from C# `It also means that there is no way to expose units of measure as part of a public API to another .NET language (except other F# assemblies).` (At the bottom of this page) https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/

Comment: Essentially, you'd use C# for display purposes, but all your scientific computations would live in F# land.  Besides, common SI units of measure are already defined, no need to reinvent a meter or a second

Comment: open FSharp.Data.UnitSystems.SI

Comment: Ah that's unfortunately not possible without a major rewrite. Which is unfortunate, it would've been cool. Right now I'm thinking of just generating the classes myself pre-build with a template and a powershell script. I'm also looking at T4 templates. this seems useful: http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Code-Generation-with-T4-Templates-e28093-A-must-have-for-developers.aspx

Comment: If I had to choose between decent compiler support and hand-crafted codegen, I'd rely on compiler every time.  Alas, tis not my decision to make